# Get result of completablefuture

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am using completablefuture to be returned from an async thread in springboot application. My implementation is below. From my understanding a new thread should be started for each item in list and should process parallely. I understand .get will block the execution but as it is parallely running still i dont see any improvement in performance. Any suggestions on below please to improve the performance?

ServiceA.java

```
@Autowired
ServiceB serviceb;


public List<String> getNames(List<Item> items) {
List<CompletableFuture<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
for( Item item: items) {
  CompletableFuture<String> getItemName = serviceb.doProcess(item);
  list.add(getItemName):
}

for( CompletableFuture name : list) {
 returnList.add(name.get());
}
return returnList;
}
```

ServiceB.java

```
Class ServiceB {
@Async
Public CompletableFuture<String> doProcess(Item item)
{
   //do process
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call [allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) to wait for all results. This will wait for all CompletableFuture to complete.

```
        List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
        CompletableFuture<String>[] tasks = items.stream()
            .map(value-> serviceb.doProcess(value).thenApply(returnList::add))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
        // wait for all tasks to finish
        CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks).get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // return the results
        return returnList;
```

Second solution would be to use an reactive approach like publisher/subscriber pattern ([Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) or [JavaRx](http://reactivex.io/)). This way your application would have little/no waiting operation. But this would affect your application architecture.

**One Advice**:
In order to create an `CompletableFuture` use the constructor with [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) in order to keep in check number of threads and have control over running threads or  when application shuts down.

Comment: I tried above. But i see that the flow is continuing without waiting for the tasks to be completed.I can see the response being returned to caller, but after that still the threads are running which means that its not waiting for the tasks to be completed.

Comment: i did a .join() .Changed this "CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks).get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);" to "CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks).get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS).join()" did the trick. Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `thenAccept` to add the items to the list.

```
List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
CompletableFuture.allOf(
    Stream.of(items).map(
        i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(i)
            .thenAccept(list::add)
    ).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
).get(10, SECONDS);

return list;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This looks the same which i have implemented. But do you mind explaining about "CopyOnWriteArrayList" and why not an simple ArrayList here?

Comment: @JingJong your adding to the list concurrently, so you need a thread-safe list. `ArrayList ` is not.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The get() will definitely not going to work out as it will block the main thread of execution to fetch the result from the async threads. A better option would be to use callback methods(thenApply() etc) accordingly so as to let the main thread continue its work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure about thenApply()  what does it do. Will definitely explore this option.